# C++ std::streampos & std::streamoff problem

Tags: c++

I've a C++ code looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <regex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <random>

std::string get_username() {
    TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
    return std::string(username);
}

std::string get_chatlog_path() {
    std::string username = get_username();
    return "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\GTA San Andreas User Files\\SAMP\\chatlog.txt";
}

std::string get_last_line(const std::string& path) {
    std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::ate);
    if (!file) return "";

    auto end = file.tellg();
    std::string line;
    while (end > 0) {
        file.seekg(static_cast<std::streampos>(--end));
        if (file.get() == '\n' && end != file.tellg()) {
            std::getline(file, line);
            break;
        }
    }
    return line;
}


int main() {
    HWND hwnd;
    std::string chatlog_path = get_chatlog_path();
    std::regex afk_regex(R"(\{FF0000\}\/afk (\d+)\{FFFF00\})");
    std::smatch afk_match;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(3000, 5000);

    while (true) {
        hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "GTA:SA:MP");
        if (!hwnd) {
            std::cout << "Waiting for GTA SAMP to open" << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        } else {
            std::cout << "GTA SAMP detected, Anti-AFK is now activated" << std::endl;
            while (hwnd) {
                std::string last_line = get_last_line(chatlog_path);
                if (std::regex_search(last_line, afk_match, afk_regex)) {
                    int afk_code = std::stoi(afk_match[1]);
                    std::cout << "AFK Code detected, it's " << afk_code << ", AFK bypassed" << std::endl;

                    std::string input_str = "t/afk " + std::to_string(afk_code);
                    std::vector<INPUT> inputs(input_str.size() + 1);

                    for (size_t i = 0; i < input_str.size(); ++i) {
                        inputs[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        inputs[i].ki.wVk = VkKeyScan(input_str[i]);
                        inputs[i].ki.dwFlags = 0;
                    }

                    inputs.back().type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                    inputs.back().ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
                    inputs.back().ki.dwFlags = 0;

                    Sleep(distr(gen));
                    SendInput(inputs.size(), inputs.data(), sizeof(INPUT));

                    std::cout << "Waiting for AFK Code" << std::endl;
                }
                hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "GTA:SA:MP");
                Sleep(1000);
            }
            std::cout << "gta_sa.exe is not found, waiting for existence" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but when i compile, it got an error :

```
main.cpp: In function 'std::string get_last_line(const string&)':
main.cpp:31:48: error: no match for 'operator--' (operand type is 'std::fpos<int>')
   31 |         file.seekg(static_cast<std::streampos>(--end));
```

Any solutions??

I want a fix or solve of this C++ code to succed to get compile

Comment: As the error states `std::fpos` simply doesn't support the decrement operator https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos, you'll need to use `end -= 1` instead